# Oracle : Update data

Tags: oracle, sql-update, plsqldeveloper

How I can  Update data with these procedure parameters.

```
 1. p_id_book IN NUMBER;
 2. p_column_name VARCHAR2;
 3. p_value VARCAHR2;
```

If I try updating like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE uptade_book(p_id_book IN NUMBER,
   p_column varchar2, p_value varchar2)
AS
  begin  
    UPDATE book SET  p_column = p_value WHERE id_book = p_id_book;
  END;
```

These errors occur:

> PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.
>
> PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "p_column: invalid identifier.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need dynamic sql for such purposes. The update could be run in an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`. It is a good practice to use `<column>%type` for parameters referring to column names.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE update_book(p_id_book book.id_book%TYPE,
                                        p_column  VARCHAR2,
                                        p_value   VARCHAR2)
AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE book SET  '||p_column||' = :p_value 
    WHERE id_book = :p_id_book'
    USING p_value, p_id_book;
END;
```

An important point to note here is that since `p_value` is defined as `VARCHAR2`, it will work fine if you pass strings or numbers. For `date` and `timestamp` types, you should take special care with respect to passing proper formats. esp. if you pass strings(instead of date), to avoid errors due to implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know your structure of `book` table, but what happen in your procedure that show to you in error :

PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored : You tried to execute an invalid block of PLSQL code (like a stored procedure or function), but a compilation error occurred.

[Oracle / PLSQL: ORA-06550 Error Message](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora06550.php)

PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "p_column: invalid identifier : You tried to execute a SQL statement that included an invalid column name or the column name is missing. This commonly occurs when you reference an invalid alias in a SELECT statement.

[Oracle / PLSQL: ORA-00904 Error Message](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00904.php)